# how to prove using induction that sum of terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Prove that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{(2i-1)}\dfrac{1}{(2i+1)}\right) = \dfrac{k}{(2k+1)}‎‎$

My Base of Induction is to check that it is true for i=1, so:

$\dfrac{1}{1}\dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{3}$.  TRUE.

I check also if it is true for i=2.

$\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{6}{15}= \dfrac{2}{5}$.  So it is also true.

My induction hypothesis is assume that it is true for i=k and then add up the (k+1) term.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2k+2-1}\dfrac{1}{2k+2+1}\right)=\\
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\dfrac{1}{2k+3}\right)=\\
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left[\dfrac{2k+3}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\dfrac{2k+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\right]=\\
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left[\dfrac{4k+4}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\right]=\\
\dfrac{k(2k+3)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)} + \left[\dfrac{4k+4}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\right]=\\
\dfrac{(2k^2+3k)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)} + \left[\dfrac{4k+4}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}\right]
\end{align*}

But I don´t know how to go any further.  What am I missing here?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{1}{2k+3}=\frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}$$ You've computed $$\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2k+2-1}\dfrac{1}{2k+2+1}\right)=\\
\dfrac{k}{2k+1} + \left(\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\dfrac{1}{2k+3}\right)=\\
\frac{k(2k+3)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)} + \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\\
\dfrac{k(2k+3)+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\\
\dfrac{2k^2+3k+1}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\\
\dfrac{(2k+1)(k+1)}{(2k+1)(2k+3)}=\\
\end{align*}$$

Hopefully you can complete from here

Comment: Yes - apologies - I wasn't sure exactly how best to point that out

Comment: Done - thx @ThomasAndrews